# How can I print a value rather than a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I solve the problem. Thank you.

---

I am implementing CNN using tensorflow in python.

```
# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x):
# Hidden fully connected layer
W1_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 1, 32], stddev=0.01))
L1_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X, W1_1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')  # (?, 192, 112, 32)
L1_1 = tf.nn.relu(L1_1)
W1_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 32, 32], stddev=0.01))
L1_2 = tf.nn.conv2d(L1_1, W1_2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')  # (?, 192, 112, 32)
L1_2 = tf.nn.relu(L1_2)
# Pooling
L1_2 = tf.nn.max_pool(L1_2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')  # (?, 96, 52 ,32)
```

W and L were too long, so I omitted them

```
# Pooling
L4_3 = tf.nn.max_pool(L4_3, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')  # (?, 12, 7 ,84)

L4_flat = tf.reshape(L4_3, [-1, 12 * 7 * 84])

hypothesis = tf.matmul(L4_flat, Weight) + Bias
return hypothesis

# Construct model
logits = multilayer_perceptron(X)

# obtain cm after training
confusion_matrix_tf = tf.confusion_matrix(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))

# Define loss and optimizer -- loss_op = cost
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)


with tf.name_scope('eval'):
pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  # Apply softmax to logits
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
# Calculate accuracy
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

total_accuracy = 0
stack = 0

with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(init)

# Training cycle
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    avg_cost = 0.
    for i in range(int(len(train_X)/(batch_size*10))):
        start = ((i + 1) * batch_size) - batch_size
        end = ((i + 1) * batch_size)
        batch_xs = train_X[start:end]
        batch_ys = train_Y[start:end]
        feed_dict = {X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys, keep_prob: keep_prob_training}
        # Run optimization op (back prop) and cost op (to get loss value)
        _, c = sess.run([train_op, cost], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        avg_cost = avg_cost + c
        # Compute average loss
        # Display logs per epoch step
    if epoch % display_step == 0:
        print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost={:.9f}".format(avg_cost/(len(train_X)/(batch_size*10))))
print("Optimization Finished!")

# Test model
for i in range(len(test_X) // batch_size):
    start = ((i + 1) * batch_size) - batch_size
    end = ((i + 1) * batch_size)
    batch_xs = test_X[start:end]
    batch_ys = test_Y[start:end]
    accuracy_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys, keep_prob: keep_prob_training})
    stack = stack + accuracy
    total_accuracy = stack / (i + 1)

print("Test Accuracy: {:04f}".format(total_accuracy)) # line 199
cm = confusion_matrix_tf.eval(feed_dict={X: test_X, Y: test_Y, keep_prob: 1.0})
print("CM=\n", cm)
```

edit:
This is the error when I run this code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/fingerPrint/CNN.py", line 199, in <module>
print("Test Accuracy: {:04f}".format(total_accuracy))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Tensor.__format__
```

line 199 : print("Test Accuracy: {:04f}".format(total_accuracy))

And I want to print cm as well.
The dataset is large and cm cannot be calculated at once.

Can the confusion matrix be calculated and added for each batch?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, and clearly explain what is it that you need, and why what you are doing currently doesn't work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added code and error. I would appreciate it if you check.

Comment: Use `total_accuracy.numpy()` to get a numpy array with the result of the tensor, then either do `.flatten()[0]` if you're 100% sure you only have one value, or print the entire array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what confusion_matrix_tf is since it's not in your code. But I assume it's some variation of https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/confusion_matrix .

If it's too big to compute at once because of the number of examples, you can compute it as part of the test iteration and just accumulate the results.

If it's just counting things accumulate the counts over your dataset (eval gives you some result, you just add it all up).

If you are already computing ratios then you need to adjust, by doing a weighted average using the number of examples in each run as weight.

If the matrix is too big because of the number of classes then there's no easy solution that I know of.

Comment: Sorry for not clear my question.
Thank you for the answer.
Added error details.